# Show hidden inline-block elements with jquery 1.9

Tags: jquery, show, hidden

I've problem with showing hidden blocks, if they are css: inline-block.

```
div.profile{
    display: inline-block;
}


<div class='profile' style='display: none;'>profile info</div>
```

But when i do $('.profile').show() it becomes style='display: block' (i can see it in firebug) and overrites my css style...

How can i fix this?

btw, in jquery 1.4 it works correctly.

Thanks.

UPD

$.css('display', 'inline-block'), imo, is not universal solution.

Comment: if i have visible inline-block, then hide() and show(), it still will be inline-block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the css style instead of using the `show` function, which changes it to `block`.

```
$('.profile').css('display', 'inline-block');
```

Comment: yes, it will works, but isn't it a jquery bug?
because, if i have visible inline-block, then hide() and show() it still will be inline-block

Comment: @DmitriyApollonin - jQuery wouldn't know if whats specified in CSS is `display: none` or not. And `.show()` has to definitely *show* it regardless of whats in the CSS. That must be the only reason. This actually more like a fix for a bug prior to 1.9.

Comment: @techfoobar sounds ok, yes, but according to documentation: 
_If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline._

so, jquery 'knows' something about specified css properties. or i am not right?

Comment: @DmitriyApollonin - If the element was first hidden *using jQuery* (prior to showing using jQuery), it may be able to remember the element's previous display state, yes (though i doubt it would have stored that).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.profile').css('display', 'inline-block')
```

Answer (score 0):

While setting it explicitly to `inline-block` works in this case, you should ideally be setting it to `''` to apply whatever comes from the CSS, be it `inline`, or `inline-block` or `block`

```
$('.profile').css('display', ''); // switch it back to whats specified in the CSS
```

Comment: Perhaps that is what JQuery should be doing in the show method.

Comment: jQuery wouldn't know if whats specified in CSS is `display: none` or not. And `.show()` has to definitely *show* it regardless of whats in the CSS. That must be the only reason.