# Single li inherits bootstrap-responsive, others inherit bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, css, show-hide, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm generating a list by PHP and hiding/showing it via jQuery in a Wordpress site.

PHP

```
<ul>
    <?php 
        $args = array(
            'type'                     => 'post',
            'child_of'                 => 622,
            'orderby'                  => 'name',
            'order'                    => 'ASC',
            'hierarchical'             => 1,
            'taxonomy'                 => 'category'
            ); 
        $categories = get_categories($args );
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            echo '<li class="problem '. $category->slug . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</li>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

JS

```
jQuery('#some_id').on('click',function(){
    jQuery('.containerclass ul li').hide(); /* hides all categories */
    jQuery('.problem').show();
    /*jQuery('.problem').css('display', 'inline-block'); Not working */
});
```

CSS

```
.problem{
    display: inline-block;
    /*float: left;*/
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: 1px solid gray;
}
```

One of the `<li>` elements in the list is toggled between `display: none` and `display: block` while all others are toggled between `display: none` and `display: inline-block`.

As in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952965/show-hidden-inline-block-elements-with-jquery-1-9), I've changed `.show()` to `.css('display', 'inline-block')` which had set all elements to `display: inline-block` however, that particular `<li>` is still shown as if it is a `block`.

[image]

I've tried also using `float:left` and removing `display: inline-block`. But same `<li>` element behaved differently causing same error. What am I missing here to correct this erroneous behavior?

**EDIT:** I tried to reproduce the problem in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhLxcxas/2/), but it works without problem there.

**EDIT 2:** Oh, guess I've found it, still don't know why it is happening. I checked the style of the erroneous element by inspect element, I found out that it uses different style. All `<li>` elements inherits style from `bootstrap.css` while that particular `<li>` inherits `bootstrap-responsive.css`, `@media (min-width: 1200px)`. What's the reason of this?

**EDIT 3:** I've corrected -cheated- the error by overriding the bootstrap-responsive style. Since it does not solves the problem, but only covers it, I'm not posting it as an answer.

```
.problem{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px!important;
    text-align: center;
    float: none!important;
    margin-left: 0!important;
    min-height: 20px!important;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way you could put this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: can you add a js-fiddle with your generated HTML, it will be more easy to understand the real issue

Comment: I thought I couldn't reproduce it in jsfiddle because of the php part at first, but I'll try to do it with the generated part, now. Thanks.

Comment: How do you determine which li to toggle display none/block? Post that logic.

Comment: I've updated the question with my new finding.